# Showing non-default fonts in .NET FontDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5, fonts

I'm using the standard .NET FontDialog to allows users to select fonts, but it's not showing all available fonts. For example, we have installed Helvetica and that's not showing. The Helvetica is a TTF if that makes a difference.

Is there any way I can get it show all available fonts?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog filters fonts that won't work in GDI+.  Device fonts and OpenType fonts won't show up, only TrueType fonts are supported.  The Helvetica font is published by Adobe, that would make it highly likely to be an OpenType font.  You would have to switch to WPF to be able to use this font.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realise that OpenType fonts also use the TTF extension.